# Not refreshing datatable inside ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am new to web development. I am trying to set the data to `datatable` after ajax success. In success method if data is available it is displaying properly but if no data getting in success method previous data refreshing.

```
$("button#search").click(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var age = $("#age").val();    
  var url = "/searchCustomer/searchCust";
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {name:name,age:age},
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
    success : function(data) {  
      var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable( {
        data : data.data,
        columns: [
          {"data": "customerid" },
          {"data": "name"},
          {"data": "mobilenumber"},
          {"data": "status"}
        ],
        "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "View _MENU_ records per page",
          "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
          "infoEmpty": "No records available",
          "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
      })
    },
    error : function(e) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
```

When clicked button first time if data available is displaying properly, second time clicked button but no data in this case old data not refreshing.

JSON data format:
1.`{"data":[{"customerid":"xxxxxxxxxx","name":"Sourabh Yadav","mobilenumber":"XXXXXXXXXXX","status":"In-Active"}]}`

2.`{"data":null}`

Comment: If you have an ID, simply use that instead of `$("button#search").click(function() {` use `$("#search").on('click', function() {`

Comment: Why would you expect the old data to still be present - when you do a new request if you are getting no data then nothing will display because there is nothing to display.  Nothing automatically saves data for you, you would have to do that yourself in some manner; for example in your `beforeSendHandler` function.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: i am also saying  same thing but old data still displaying but i don't need it. i think `datatable` not refreshing.

Comment: You must have to remove old data and then have append new data in datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the datatable using `fnClearTable()` if there is no data. Use this in the success of ajax:

```
var dataTable = $('#customerTable').dataTable();
if (data.data == null) {
    dataTable.fnClearTable();
} else {
    // set your datatable here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it empty before every ajax call `$('#customerTable').empty()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as you have to already loaded table instance and then empty the data and then re initialize

```
$("button#search").click(function() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var age = $("#age").val();    
  var url = "/searchCustomer/searchCust";
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {name:name,age:age},
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
    success : function(data) {  
        if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#customerTable') ) {
            $('#customerTable').DataTable().destroy();
        }

        $('#customerTable').empty();

      var table = $('#customerTable').DataTable( {
        data : data.data,
        columns: [
          {"data": "customerid" },
          {"data": "name"},
          {"data": "mobilenumber"},
          {"data": "status"}
        ],
        "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "View _MENU_ records per page",
          "zeroRecords": "No matching records found",
          "infoEmpty": "No records available",
          "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        },
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
      })
    },
    error : function(e) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
```